# How to change the background color of this tikz rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,pstricks,dvipsnames,border={1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt}]{standalone}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{tikz} % To plot almost everything.

% TIKZ LIBRARIES & SETTINGS

\usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, matrix, positioning, arrows.meta, intersections, through, backgrounds, patterns, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

% FIGURE 1

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,rounded corners=0.25pt]
\begin{scope}[line width=1.5pt]
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05](6,5) rectangle (26,20);
\draw[black] (6,2) rectangle (30,20) (30,20) node[black,below left,scale=1] {$V_c$};
\filldraw[pattern=crosshatch,pattern color=black,opacity=0.20] (6,5) rectangle (26,20);
\filldraw[color=white, fill=black!0.2,opacity=1.0](8.5,3) rectangle +(19.5,9) (7,6);
\draw[black] (8.5,3) rectangle +(19.5,9) (28,12) node[black,below left,scale=1] {$V_f$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (8.5,3) rectangle +(19.5,9) (28,12);
\draw[black] (4,4) rectangle (31,24) (31,24) node[black,below left,scale=1] {$V_n$}; 
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (4,4) rectangle (31,24) (31,24); 
\draw[black] (2,5) rectangle (26,23) (2,23) node[black,below right,scale=1] {$V_m$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (2,5) rectangle (26,23) (2,23);
\filldraw[color=white, fill=black!0.2, opacity=1.0](8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13);
\draw[black] (8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13) node[black,midway,scale=1] {$V_\kappa$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13);
\draw[black] (9.5,6) rectangle +(15.5,5) (9.5,6) node[black,above right,scale=1] {$V_o$}; 
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (9.5,6) rectangle +(15.5,5) (9.5,6); 
\fill[black] (21.0,8.5) circle(.25) +(0,0) node[black,right,scale=1] {$\nu_u$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (21.0,8.5) circle(.25) +(0,0);
\draw[black] (19.0,10.0) rectangle (13,7.0) (16.0,9) node[midway,black,scale=1] {$V_d$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (19.0,10.0) rectangle (13,7.0);
\draw (6,5) node[black, above right, scale=1] {$V_p$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

% FIGURE 2

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,rounded corners=0.25pt]
\begin{scope}[line width=1.5pt]
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05](6,5) rectangle (26,20);
\draw[black] (6,2) rectangle (30,20) (30,20) node[black,below left,scale=1] {$V_c$};
\filldraw[pattern=crosshatch,pattern color=black,opacity=0.20] (6,5) rectangle (26,20);
\filldraw[color=white, fill=black!0.2,opacity=1.0](8.5,3) rectangle +(19.5,9) (7,6);
\draw[black] (8.5,3) rectangle +(19.5,9) (28,12) node[black,below left,scale=1] {$V_f$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (8.5,3) rectangle +(19.5,9) (28,12);
\draw[black] (4,4) rectangle (31,24) (31,24) node[black,below left,scale=1] {$V_n$}; 
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (4,4) rectangle (31,24) (31,24); 
\draw[black] (2,5) rectangle (26,23) (2,23) node[black,below right,scale=1] {$V_m$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (2,5) rectangle (26,23) (2,23);
\filldraw[color=white, fill=black, opacity=1.0](8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13);
\draw[black] (8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13) node[black,midway,scale=1] {$V_\kappa$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13);
\draw[black] (9.5,6) rectangle +(15.5,5) (9.5,6) node[black,above right,scale=1] {$V_o$}; 
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (9.5,6) rectangle +(15.5,5) (9.5,6); 
\fill[black] (21.0,8.5) circle(.25) +(0,0) node[black,right,scale=1] {$\nu_u$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (21.0,8.5) circle(.25) +(0,0);
\draw[black] (19.0,10.0) rectangle (13,7.0) (16.0,9) node[midway,black,scale=1] {$V_d$};
\filldraw[color=black,opacity=0.05] (19.0,10.0) rectangle (13,7.0);
\draw (6,5) node[black, above right, scale=1] {$V_p$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

The problem I have is the following. The rectangle containing $V_\kappa$ in Figure 1 should be of color `\black!0.2`. However, when I specify so using `\filldraw[color=white, fill=black!0.2, opacity=1.0](8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13);`, the background of such triangle is white. If, however, I instead use `\filldraw[color=white, fill=black, opacity=1.0](8.5,13) rectangle +(15,6) (7,13);` the background of the $V_k$ rectangle is black (as it should as specified by the code; see Figure 2). How can I get the $V_\kappa$ rectangle to be of color `black!0.2`? Apparently I can only give it "full" colours, and I really don't know why.

Comment: If I use a color picker on your first rectangle I have `#f1f1f1` which is *not* white. Depending on the gamma of your display, it could well be `black!0.2`. Have you tried `black!0.3`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried many different colors combined with many !0.X, and only "full" colors are displayed as expected. So, `black!0.2` and `black0.9` produce the same result. But `black` produces the expected result. I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: Note that the number after the `!` goes from 0 to 100. So, `black!0.2` is a very light gray.

Comment: @JasperHabicht you're right, I missed that! Try `black!20`... ;-)

Comment: You're both right. I thought it went from 0 to 1... My bad. Shall I erase the question?

Comment: Yes - please delete the question. I and others waste time trying to understand the problem, until it is revealed in the comments that there is no problem. The question is not likely to help others as the title does not say anything about the `color!xx` notation or mixing colors, or transparency.

Comment: Maybe it is not necessary to delete this question, but I am still voting to close it because  the problem has been solved in the comments.